# Jquery response showing response but is not being evaluated as true

Tags: jquery

Here's my jquery code

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "<MY URL IN HERE>",
  type: "post",             
  success: function (response) {                            
    if(response=='hello'){
      alert('YES success');
    } else {
      alert('test1' + response);
    }
  }                     
});
```

It's showing the alert test1hello which is signifying that response's value is hello, however, why is it not showing YES Success?

Comment: do a console.log(">>"+response+"<<");  this will give you the value that is coming in response exactly

Comment: try `if (response.trim() == 'hello') {` to strip away hidden characters. If that works, my guess is you have an encoding issue. Make sure all your files are UTF-8 without BOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the server response has a space or new line. Try using [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)
`$.trim(response) == 'hello'` instead of `response == 'hello'`

Similar question was answered here: [jQuery 'If' statement string comparison not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233422/jquery-if-statement-string-comparison-not-working)

Comment: Yes there was white space that I didn't see. Thanks!